# Closing an open recordset produces a run-time error

Tags: vba, excel, database-connection

I have an ADO recordset variable that is declared in the class module of a userform. The recordset is opened in the form's Activate event, and I am trying to close it in the form's Terminate event with code like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()

If VersionIsReleased Then
    ThisWorkbook.Parent.Quit
Else

    If Not m_rs Is Nothing Then

        If m_rs.State = adStateOpen Then
            m_rs.Close
        End If

        Set m_rs = Nothing
    End If

    Close_CN g_cn
    ThisWorkbook.Application.Visible = True
End If

End Sub
```

The line `m_rs.Close` produces a run-time error: "Operation is not allowed in this context.". Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: I wonder if the variable is already destroyed by the time you run the Terminate event?

Comment: Also, maybe you don't need to explicitly kill it as **according to Microsoft** - see [MSDN Blog entry on this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/04/28/when-are-you-required-to-set-objects-to-nothing.aspx) - the variable will be out of scope (and therefoore destroyed) when the userform is unloaded from memory

Comment: As a general comment - you would like to avoid any run-time errors in the finalisers/deconstructors/exit handlers. In this case I would put On Error Resume Next as a first line.

Comment: @Philip: To get to that line the variable can't have been destroyed, because it's State is adStateOpen. I suppose I could let Excel destroy it when the userform is unloaded, but wouldn't that lead to memory problems?

Comment: it shouldn't do, as the Garbage Collector should be able to handle it. Traditionally programmers gaine dthe habit of explicitly closing db connections because of resource managemnt issues in early versions of ADo/DAO RDO etc, but I don't know if it's necessary any longer in these days of high network bandwidth availability and cheap server memory...Personally, I have always tried to close and destroy connection/recordset objects as a matter of habit but I honestly couldn't say it's necessary.

Comment: Also, if **m_rs** is declared explicitly / *strongly typed* using **Dim m_rs As ...** then it will **never** be nothing! More info on this can be found on the Platform SDK: [Improving MDAC Application Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810818.aspx)

Comment: Using `set m_rs = nothing` will close the connection or recordset. The close method is a red herring to make excel happy.

Comment: This is what i found anyway... how are you defining this variable?

Comment: What is the value of the EditMode property before you close? Maybe you've updated a field but not performed the .Update method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That error can occur if the recordset is being edited when you try to close it. Make sure that if you use `AddNew` or change any `Fields().Value` that you use `Update` to save the edits before closing.  You can inspect the `EditMode` property to see what state the recordset is in.